# How to return recursively modified arrays in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, recursion, pass-by-reference

I am trying to implement algorithm in matlab, the algorithm that takes a set of points and a subset of it called anchor points, the algorithm work as follows:

1. Find the two farthest anchor points
2. Split the points into two groups by associating each point to the closest anchor point
3. Recursively repeat the process until each group has only one anchor point
4. Return the groups that has one anchor points

The problem is that MatLab does not allow modification of arrays by reference, although the groups are formulated I cant return them in a proper way.

How can I overcome this issue??

The following is my code:

```
function [part1, part2, part1anchors, part2anchors] = iterativeSpletting(points, anchors)
dist = @(a, b) ((a.xd - b.xd) ^ 2 + (a.yd - b.yd) ^ 2) ^ 0.5;

%find farthest two anchors
[ch1, ch2] = FarthestPoints(anchors);

%find parts
for i = 1:numel(points)
    if (dist(points(i), ch1) <= dist(points(i), ch2))
        part1 = [part1, points(i)];
    else
        part2 = [part2, points(i)];
    end
end

%assing anchors to parts
for i = 1:numel(anchors)
    if (dist(anchors(i), ch1) <= dist(anchors(i), ch2))
        part1anchors = [part1anchors, anchors(i)];
    else
        part2anchors = [part2anchors, anchors(i)];
    end
end

if numel(part1anchors) == 1
    %how to return the part    
else
    iterativeSpletting(part1, part1anchors)
end

if numel(part2ch2) == 1
    %how to return the part
else
    iterativeSplitting(part2, part2anchors)
end
end
```

Comment: show us what you tried...

Answer (score 1):

Closures are captured by reference. If you want to recursively modify one big array you can code like this:

```
function MyArray = foo()
    MyArray = zeros(1, 100);
    function bar(l, r)
        if l < r
            MyArray(l:r) = MyArray(l:r) + 1;
            bar(l+1, r - 1);
        end
    end      
    bar(1, 100);          
end
```

`A = f(A)` also works fine (Matlab usually optimizes it to avoid unnecessary copying)